# Partial page are not loading on same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here is my code has been implemented in a .chtml page. When I click on button corresponding page open in new page instead of same page. I want to open that partial page on same view page. please help me..  Thanks in advance..

```
  <div class="contentbox">
        <div class="contentmain">
          @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchForEdit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "update_panel", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
          {                
             <ul>
                <li><div class="leftc_box" style="width:150px;">Enter Id or Song Name </div>
                <div class="rightc_box">
                <input type="text" name="entryid" value="" placeholder="Enter Id or Song Name" style="height: 30px;"  />
                </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <div class="leftc_box" style="margin-left:153px;"><input type="image" name="" src="../../Content/img/submit.png" value="" /></div>
                </li>
            </ul>              
                <div id="update_panel">@Html.Partial("SearchForEdit")</div>                                                         
          }
            <div>
                <table style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; height: auto; width: 100%; margin-top: 8px;">
                    <tr style="background: #f4f4f4;">
                        <th align="center">ID</th>
                        <th align="center">Song Name</th>
                        <th align="center">Album Name</th>
                        <th align="center">Label Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (xxxxxxxxxxx ienctry in obmain)
                    {
                        <tr class="divset">
                            <td align="center">@ienctry.id</td>
                            <td align="center">@ienctry.Song</td>
                            <td align="center">@ienctry.Album</td>
                            <td align="center">@ienctry.Label</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>               
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my controller is this..

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchForEdit(int entryid)
        {
            ViewBag.searchid = entryid;
            return PartialView("SearchForEdit");
        }
```

Here is my partial page...

```
@{    
    int ssid = 0;
     if(ViewBag.searchid!=null)
     {
         ssid = ViewBag.searchid;
     }
                      List<XXXXXXXX> mainobject = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.Service.Class1.SearchnUpdate(ssid);
                      ViewBag.Title = "title";

}

<div>
 <table style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; height: auto; width: 100%; margin-top: 8px;">

@if (mainobject.Count > 0)
{
     <tr style="background: #f4f4f4;">
                            <th align="center">ID</th>
                            <th align="center">Song Name</th>
                            <th align="center">Album Name</th>
                            <th align="center">Label Name</th>
                            <th align="center"></th>
                        </tr>
    foreach (XXXXXXXXXX ientry in mainobject)
    {
   <tr style="background: #f4f4f4;">
    <td align="center">@ientry.id</td>
    <td align="center">@ientry.Song</td>
    <td align="center">@ientry.Album</td>
    <td align="center">@ientry.Label</td>
    <td align="right"><a href=""><img src="../../Content/img/update.png"</a></td>
    </tr>
}
}
</table>
</div>
```

Here is my method has been defined in class1 page..

```
public static List<xxxx> SearchnUpdate(int searchid)
        {
            string ssongname=searchid.ToString();
            List<xxxx> obj = new List<xxxx>();
            using (xxxxxxxxx dbcontext = new xxxxxxxxxx())
            {
                obj = (from z in dbcontext.xxxxx where z.id == searchid || z.Song == ssongname select z).ToList();
            }
            return obj;
        }
```

Comment: As `awesome` was implying, the usual cause for `Ajax.BeginForm` submitting normally is that the relevant Ajax responsive js files are missing. Check what js files you have (or don't have) in your project. Run fiddler2 to see if something is not downloading that you are expecting.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I have all reqired JS and same concept is working with my  another project but in this project I'm getting that above issue.

Comment: I have added <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> js

Comment: not yet sir... I have tried so much... but my problem is remain

Comment: Are you sure the submit button (which in your example is actually just an image) is actually submitting the form?

Comment: @Green yes sir.. That button is an submit button and working fine